# Shortening menu item names for narrow screens

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

How would you go about shortening navigational menu item names when the browser window is made narrower? Is that possible with CSS media queries, or would you need to use JavaScript?

There is an example of this on smashingmagazine.com. The menu item "WORDPRESS" shortens to "WP" when the browser window gets narrow enough.

Comment: You can't do this with CSS explicitly without `:before`/`:after`+`content`, which would probably be a bit weird.  What have you tried with JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two different spans for example in the same li which displays for different media queries:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <span class="show-desktop">Wordpress</span>
      <span class="show-mobile">WP</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, the show-desktop class is used for wider screens, show-mobile class is used for smaller/narrower screens.

Comment: It works with any CSS that uses media queries that have defined .show-desktop to be hidden on small screens and .show-mobile to be hidden on wider screens. Bootstrap might use other classes, I just made these up as I wrote :)

Comment: True. I guess Bootstrap's are slightly different. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it's actually .visible-phone and .visible-desktop, close though! :)